# Defining a custom type that works with `typing.get_type_hints()`

Tags: python, type-hinting

I want to use a type hint that is an object with some structure, as follows:

```
import typing


class MyType:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param


def func(a: MyType(1)):
    pass


print(typing.get_type_hints(func))
```

This runs fine, producing

```
{'a': <__main__.MyType object at 0x107a3c110>}
```

But if one adds

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

at the beginning of the code, mimicking the default behavior of Python 3.8+ (converting the annotation to a string that gets evaluated in `get_type_hints()`), it produces an error

```
TypeError: Forward references must evaluate to types. Got <__main__.MyType object at 0x10f4ff0d0>
```

Is it possible to make this work with the new annotation behavior? As far as I understand I need to subclass `MyType` making its objects types themselves, but I cannot figure out which base class I am supposed to use.

Comment: Your type hint makes no sense. `MyType(1)` is not a type, it's an object. You don't pass values of type `MyType(1)`, you pass values of type `MyType`.

Comment: See my comment below. `typing` is full of such pseudo-types, and they make perfect sense.

Comment: I don't understand how it makes sense in this example. It would make sense to me if `MyClass(1)` returned a `type` object, but it doesn't, it returns an instance of `MyClass`. How can you expect an object of type `MyClass(1)` if `MyClass(1)` isn't a type?

Comment: That's exactly the question I'm asking - how to subclass it to make it a type. If the example is too abstract for you, in a real application it is an array type with partially defined shape, e.g. `Array(..., 100)`. This way an object of type `Array(10, 100)` will be an instance of this type.

Comment: That makes more sense, so what's stopping you from just...creating the type `Array100` manually? Presumably, you want a bunch of types generated at runtime. Considering the point of type hints is to be used *not during runtime* I don't see the benefit of doing that. Seems far easier to just add a check for the size of the passed objects, for example. But yes, as your answer hints, metaprogramming is probably the only way to accomplish this.

Comment: Just for fun, if you haven't seen David Beazley's excellent [Python 3 metaprogramming tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPiWg5jSoZI), you might want to check it out. It's very long, very detailed, and super entertaining.

Comment: First, in Python type hints may be evaluated at runtime (and starting from 3.8, *have* to be), so there's no contradiction there. Second, creating a type manually is exactly what I'm doing in my answer. In the application I will need a bunch of utility methods for this type, so just calling `types.new_class()` doesn't cut it. "Seems far easier to just add a check for the size of the passed objects, for example" - not if you want to generate some C code based on the type annotations for the function, but that's getting even deeper in the real application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a possible approach is to create a metaclass:

```
class MyType(type):

    def __new__(cls, param):
        return super().__new__(cls, f'MyType({param})', (MyType,), {})

    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
```

This satisfies `get_type_hints()`.

`typing` has its own metaclasses defined, but they are all marked as private and are not documented, so it is better not to touch them.

Answer (score 0):

`typing.get_type_hints()` will try to transform any annotations which might be [forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) into types.

In your example, the annotation of `a` is not a subclass of `type`, because it is an *instance* of `MyType`. `MyType` itself *is* a subclass of `type`.

Perhaps your code is meant to say this? Annotating your function with an instance of the type doesn't make much sense in most cases.

```py
def func(a: MyType):
    pass
```

Comment: A type is an object like everything else in Python. An object like `typing.Type[int]` is not a true type, but it works in type annotations. I just want to create my own parametric type.